# Running PGAdmin after Silent installation, what is the login?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I started an installation of Postgres in unatended mode with the commandline:

```
postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "password" --servicename "postgreSQL"
--servicepassword "password" --serverport 5432
```

After the installation is finished i want to login to the database with pgadmin. i tried with "password" but i get the error:

> fatal password authentication failed for user postgres

so what are my login data for the installed database?

Thanks a lot

Marcel

Comment: You need to use the password specified with `--superpassword`. The `--servicepassword` is only for the **Windows** account, not the database superuser

Comment: In this case both are identical. both are "password". It doesnt work with "password"

Comment: Of corse without the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the password you have to change the pg_hba.conf file that contains all the authentication information.

You can read about how it works here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

I suggest you to create a backup of the original file first and to reboot the server after changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It looked like there was a conflict with previous installations of Postgres. 
I could login using the password specified by --superpassword after cleaning all Postgres-related folders in program files as well as in custom install locations.

A professional approach would be running your installer on a clean system or a VM.